# difference between return and return 1 in TCL proc

Tags: tcl

Is there any difference between **return and return 1** at the end of the proc in tcl?   Is there any difference between **return and return 1** at the end of the proc in tcl?

Comment: `return` equals `return None`

Comment: @KlausD: no, `return None` returns `None` which is not equal to the empty string `return` returns.

Comment: @PeterLewerin might be a misunderstanding, the question was originally tagged as Python.

Answer (score 2):

The Tcl `return` command will simply return the empty string if you don't tell it to return anything else. These three are all exactly equivalent:

```
return
```

```
return ""
```

```
return {}
```

Obviously, `return 1` is something else.

Answer (score 1):

"return" return none.
This display nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

 proc helloWorld {} {
   return 
 }
 puts [helloWorld]
```

"return 1" return the value 1.
This display 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc helloWorld {} {
  return 1
}
puts [helloWorld]
```